# JqueryUI "slide" effect not working

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slide

I'm working with jQueryUI in a website project, the slide effect works fine in a DIV without divs inside (#sectionOverlay). The problem appears when I try to apply the same in a DIV with more divs inside it (when #btnClose gets clicked, #sectionInfo just disappear)

http://jsfiddle.net/fB4bw/

Wish you can help me, regards!

HTML:

```
<div id="sectionCarrousel">

            <div class="carrousel_navigation" id="navPrev"></div>

            <div id="sectionProducts" class="imageflow"></div>

            <div class="carrousel_navigation" id="navNext"></div>

            <div id="sectionInfo">
                <img id="imgTitle" src="img/chips/1_name.png" alt="" />
                <a id="btnClose">
                    <img src="img/button_close.png" alt="" />
                </a>

                <div id="sectionDescription">
                    <p>PLACE HOLDER TEXT: consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lacinia consequat enim. Suspendisse gravida pellentesque dui, sed commodo ligula auctor ut. Duis scelerisque vehicula neque, vel ultrices ipsum aliquam in. In eget erat id nulla elementum rutrum. Aliquam at est nibh, ac elementum est. Donec quis ligula vel ipsum vestibulum rutrum vel eget magna. Morbi ultricies convallis ultrices. Donec a urna eu augue mattis ullamcorper sit amet eget lectus. Praesent mauris dui, posuere eget dignissim at, cursus vitae mi. Suspendisse convallis lacinia ligula, vel porttitor arcu euismod at. Sed tincidunt massa in justo consequat ac feugiat risus ornare. Maecenas accumsan risus at dui hendrerit molestie. Proin eu eros nec diam dignissim consequat sit amet mollis ipsum. Vestibulum tincidunt ligula ac purus dictum porttitor.</p>
                </div>

                <div id="sectionShare">
                    <img src="img/txt_share.png" alt="" />
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?=URL?>" target="_blank">
                        <img src="img/icon_facebook.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?=TXT_TW_SHARE?> <?=URL?>" target="_blank">
                        <img src="img/icon_twitter.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="sectionLogoBarcel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sectionOverlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #sectionCarrousel
{
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    height: 415px;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*min-width: 1280px;*/
    text-align: center;
    /*margin-bottom: 100px;*/
}

#sectionOverlay
{
    background-color: #260101;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#sectionInfo
{
    background-color: #4EA012;
    height: 300px;
    left: 230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -345px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 490;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
function HideInfo()
{
    $("#sectionInfo").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

    $("#sectionOverlay").fadeOut(500);


//    blnOverlayVisible = false;
}

function changeInfo(id, force)
{
    if(force)
    {
        $("#sectionOverlay").fadeIn(500);
        blnOverlayVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!blnOverlayVisible) return;
    }

    var description = "";

    $("#sectionInfo").fadeOut(function()
    {
        for(var i in products)
        {
            if(products[i].id == id)
            {
                description = products[i].description;
                break;
            }
        }

        $("#imgTitle").attr("src", "img/chips/" + id + "_name.png");
        $("#sectionDescription p").html(description);

        $(this).fadeIn().css("visibility","visible");
    });

$("#btnClose").click(HideInfo);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Several errors in the code. Let's see what we can get fixed and then go from there. [Edits code] After editing and setting up locally all I see is a blank screen. After edits are approved get some content in there including the button and we'll look at the Slide problem.